# Hive query throw "code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask" exception when query has GROUP BY cluase

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-tez

**I have Hive + LLAP on HDP 3.1.4**

Hive and Tez Config is:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 40960
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 1024
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 40960
hive.tez.container.size = 4096
num_llap_nodes=4
hive.llap.daemon.num.executors=8
hive.llap.daemon.yarn.container.mb = 35840
llap_headroom_space=2048
llap_heap_size=32768
hive.llap.io.memory.size=1024
tez.am.resource.memory.mb=4096
hive.tez.java.opts=-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:NewRatio=8 -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps **-Xmx3276m**
tez.runtime.io.sort.mb= 1638
tez.runtime.unordered.output.buffer.size-mb=409
```

The following query runs properly:

```
select count(*) from balance;
```

but when use group by expression in the following query:

```
select count(*),jobdate from balance group by jobdate;
```

I
I've tried many configurations but this long exception is thrown:

```
ERROR: Error while processing statement: **FAILED: Execution Error, 
    return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.** 
    Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, 
    vertexId=vertex_1617520101397_0014_1_00, diagnostics=[Task 
    failed, taskId=task_1617520101397_0014_1_00_000013, 
    diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, **info=[Error: Error while 
    running task ( failure ) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could 
    not initialize class 
    org.apache.tez.runtime.library.api.TezRuntimeConfiguration**    at 

    **BLABLA**
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ]], Task failed, 
    taskId=task_1617520101397_0014_1_00_000006, 
    diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while 
    running task ( failure ) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could 
    not initialize class 
    org.apache.tez.runtime.library.api.TezRuntimeConfiguration  at 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ]], Task failed, 
    taskId=task_1617520101397_0014_1_00_000005, 
    diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while 
    running task ( failure ) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could 
    not initialize class 
    org.apache.tez.runtime.library.api.TezRuntimeConfiguration  at 
    org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:111) 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ]], **Vertex did not 
    succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:9 killedTasks:31761, 
    Vertex vertex_1617520101397_0014_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due 
    to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, 
    vertexId=vertex_1617520101397_0014_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex 
    received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due 
    to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:18, Vertex 
    vertex_1617520101397_0014_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due 
    to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to 
    VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1 Error Code: 2**
```

Comment: I tried many configs based on the following references:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Hive-LLAP-deep-dive/ta-p/248893
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Demystify-Apache-Tez-Memory-Tuning-Step-by-Step/ta-p/245279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sections for set **hive.tez.container.size** in Ambari Hive Config page. One of them appears in the **SETTINGS** tab and the other that has related to LLAP goes under the **Advanced hive-interactive-site** in the **ADVANCED** tab. I was trying with **hive.tez.container.size** value the SETTINGS tab instead of **Advanced hive-interactive-site** section. Finally, I set the following configs and the error solved:

```
set hive.tez.container.size=10240;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx9216m;
set tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=3072;
set tez.runtime.unordered.output.buffer.size-mb=1024;
```

Comment: where do you do the set part? In localhost:4200 shell or in the Ambari Hive config UI.